# add short description to fields

Tags: php, wordpress, function, input

I have this function to add new user fields in WordPress admin user profile page.

```
function modify_user_contact_methods( $user_contact ) {

    // Add user contact methods
    $user_contact['skype']   = __( 'Skype Username'   );
    $user_contact['phone'] = __( 'Phone' );

    return $user_contact;
}
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'modify_user_contact_methods' );
```

With above code, only the field is displayed, and I want to add a description after it as shown below.

```
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="regular-text">
<p class="description">Your phone number.</p>
```

How can I add a short description like above?

Comment: This is not possible using above hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use above hook if you are looking for description. However, you can use the following method.

**Code to output fields**

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h2><?php _e("Extra Contact Info", "textdomain"); ?></h2>

    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="skype"><?php _e("Skype Username"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="skype" id="skype" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'skype', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your skype."); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="phone"><?php _e("Phone"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'phone', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your phone."); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php }
```

**Code to Save Fields**

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'skype', $_POST['skype'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', $_POST['phone'] );
}
```